# Netbeans для C+ в Ubuntu. Как подключить библиотеку POSIX для очередей сообщений mqueue.h?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, многопоточность, netbeans, библиотеки

Подключил библиотеки:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
```

Netbeans позволяет использовать функции из включенных библиотек при написании кода, однако при сборке выдает сообщения:

1. undefined reference to `mq_open'
2. undefined reference to `mq_receive'
3. undefined reference to `mq_close'
4. undefined reference to `pthread_create'

Не завершая сборку проекта.

В разделе "библиотеки" компоновщика добавив из стандартных библиотек "Потоки выполнения Posix" вопросы к `<pthread.h>` пропадают. 
Но как решить проблему с `<mqueue.h>`?

Comment: Возможно поможет компилирование с флагами `-pthread` и `-lrt`